# Remove "Statistics" Header in Stargazer Summary Stat

Tags: stargazer

I'm trying to use stargazer to output my summary stat, but I was wondering if there was any way to remove the "Statistic" label at the top left of the output. Thanks!

```
stargazer(data, 
          summary.stat = c("mean", "median", "sd", "min", "max"),
          type="text")

==================================================================
Statistic                      Mean  Median St. Dev.  Min    Max  
------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not an elegant solution, but it works for my purposes when I needed to make modifications to stargazer output.

I output the stargazer output (text, latex or html) into a variable, then manipulate it with `stringr::`.

Like I said, it's not an elegant solution, but for me, it definitely works.

```
library(stringr)
table_1 <- stargazer(mtcars, summary.stat = c("mean", "median", "sd", "min", "max"),
          type="text")

table_1 %>% str_replace("Statistic", "     ")
```

gives:

```
 [2] "==============================================="
 [3] "          Mean   Median St. Dev.  Min    Max  " 
 [4] "-----------------------------------------------"
 [5] "mpg       20.091   19.2   6.027     10     34  "
```

As I mentioned, it does work for html and latex output, too.